# jQuery get value from form object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following form:

```
<form>
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="1" checked="checked" />
  <input type="radio" name="foo" value="0" />
  <input name="this" value="xxx" />
  <select name="bar">
    <option value="hi" selected="selected">Hi</option>
    <option value="ho">Ho</option>
  </select>
  <a class="js-add" href="#" >Add</a>  
 </form>
```

I have the following function which passes the entire form when the add link is clicked:

```
$(".js-add").click(function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   values = getFormValues($("form"));
});

 getFormValues = function($form)  {
    var bar = $form.bar.val();

 }
```

How do I retrieve a particular input value from the form object. So for example in the above `getFormValues` function I want to grab the value of the bar input field but the above doesn't work. Normally I'd just do this: `$bar.val();` But how do I get the same from the form object?

Comment: Why can't you just do `$('id').val()`?

Comment: Using jquery method like `.find()` is better but you need to change `$form.bar.val()` to `$form[0].bar.val()` and add `return` at the end of function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're passing into your function isn't a form object, it's a jQuery object which is wrapped around an `HTMLFormElement` object. jQuery's API lets you easily find elements within that element via [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) (one of the [*tree traversal* methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/)):<sup>1</sup>

```
$form.find("[name=bar]").val()
```

Then you need to **return** that value from your function, so:

```
return $form.find("[name=bar]").val();
```

If the name isn't a valid CSS *identifier* (it is in your example, but...), use quotes around it:

```
return $form.find("[name='bar']").val();
```

---

<sup>1</sup> It's pretty easy with the native DOM as well, but you're using jQuery, so...

Comment: Also `$form[0].bar.val()` return value.

Comment: @Mohammad: No, that will cause an error. `$($form[0].bar).val()` would do it.

Comment: @Mohammad typically if you have to use a static array index, it's not the best method. It may work, but there are better ways.

Comment: @Mohammad: I think you mean `$form[0].bar.value`, as `$form[0].bar` is the reference to the `select` element: https://jsfiddle.net/x2hguksL/ But yes, forms have automatic properties for their inputs. *(Edit: Ah, the follow-up comment is gone now.)*